# Выбока jquery DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здраствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как средствами `jquery/phpQuery` вытащить  в переменную значение `window.open` или хотя бы `onlick` из обьекта

```
 <tr style = "cursor: pointer" 
        onmouseover = "this.setAttribute('class', 'rowSelected');" 
        onmouseout = "this.setAttribute('class', '');" 
        onclick = "if (event.ctrlKey || event.button == 1) 
        { window.open('/trade/view/purchase/general.html?id=100931803', '_blank'); } 
        else 
        { window.location='/trade/view/purchase/general.html?id=100931803'; }" >  

         <td style = "white-space: nowrap;" rowspan = "1colspan="1">258ОАОФ</td> 

    </tr>`
```

Спасибо.

Comment: куда вытащить ?откуда вытащить ?

Comment: Я же указал пример обьекта с данными

Comment: отформатируйте свой код,чтобы было понятнее

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($object->find('tr') as $items){

    $res[] =   (pq($items))->attr("onclick");

}
```

(Для phpQuery). Проблема была в правильном формировании обьекта